# Code is very slow and almost never ending - Dask dataframe assign column to a dictionary

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I have 1M dask dataframe rows. I'm trying to assign a dictionary value to a new column to the data frame.

```
df = df.assign(c=lambda x: {"a": x.a, "b": x.b})

print(df.compute())
```

What is the most optimal way to achieve this?

PS: I'm trying to track the progress using a progress bar, where the code is really fast up to 67% and it hangs up. My CPU and memory were consumed very less, but the code was running and it felt like never going to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following?  (untested)

```
df["c"] = df.apply(lambda row: {"a": row.a, "b": row.b})
```